# Can somebody explain this Javascript method?

Tags: javascript, string, window, reverse

Original source: http://twitter.com/tobeytailor/status/8998006366

```
(x=[].reverse)() === window // true
```

I've noticed that this behavior affects all the native types.  What exactly is happening here?

Comment: `[].reverse.call(y) === y` for all scalars `y`.

Comment: *I've noticed that this behavior...*   What behavior?

Comment: This now throws an error in more modern engines since `Array.prototype.reverse` is set in strict mode, where an undefined `this` value is actually `undefined` and no longer `globalThis` (i.e. `window` in browsers, `global` in Node.js).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is to do with the weird way `this` binding works in JavaScript.

```
[].reverse
```

is the method `reverse` on an empty list. If you call it, through one of:

```
[].reverse();
[]['reverse']();
([].reverse)();
```

then it executes with `this` bound to the list instance `[]`. But if you detach it:

```
x= [].reverse;
x();
```

it executes with no `this`-binding, so `this` in the function points to the global (`window`) object, in one of JavaScript's worst, most misleading design mistakes.

```
(x=[].reverse)()
```

Is also doing the detach. The assignment operator returns the same function object it was passed so it looks like it's doing nothing, but it has the side-effect of breaking the limited special case that causes JavaScript to bind `this`.

So you are saying:

```
Array.prototype.reverse.call(window)
```

`reverse`, like many other `Array.prototype` methods, is defined by ECMAScript to work on any native sequence-like object. It reverses the items with number-string keys (up to `object.length`) and returns the object. So it'll return the object that was passed in for any type that has a `length` property.

`window` has a length property, which corresponds to `window.frames.length`, so calling this method with `this` pointing at `window` will work and return the `window`. In theory it may still fail, because:

1. `window` is allowed to be a “host object” rather than a “native object”; in this case the guarantees about what you can pass to other prototypes' methods don't necessarily apply; and
2. if the window actually has frames/iframes, it would try to reverse their order, which wouldn't work because the frame collection is read-only.

However, in current browsers the former case does work and the latter fails silently without an error, so you still get the `===window` behaviour and not an Exception.

Comment: Do you happen to know why it is that somebody would code that up?  I mean, I understand why the effect happens of course, but why would I put that in my code?  What does it achieve?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. It's just showing off one of JavaScript's many unexpected behaviours. If I found this in real code I'd worry!

Comment: A possible reason to do this might be to check if some other script messed with the window object (`window = open('http://google.com/')` is enough). 
`var window = (x=[].reverse)();` could restore it locally.